# Expected Value of randomVariable

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, random-variables, expected-value

What is the Expected Value of a Random Variable that takes value $\frac{1}{2^k}$ for positive integer $k$ and probability $P(Y=\frac{1}{2^k})= \frac{1}{2^k}$ for each $k$?

I know that $E[Y]=\sum P(Y)Y$ and this is a geometric series, but I am not sure how to solve from here.

$$E[Y]= 1/2 \times 1/2 + 1/4 \times  1/4 + 1/8 \times 1/8 + \cdots + 1/k \times 1/k$$

Comment: what is the $r$ of this geometric series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use your formula directly you obtain
$$E[Y]=\sum_{k\geq 1}\dfrac{1}{2^k}\dfrac{1}{2^k}=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\dfrac{1}{4^k} - 1=\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}} - 1=\dfrac{1}{3}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! Where does the '-1 'come from?

Comment: To use the formula $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}} p^k = \dfrac{1}{1-p}$ you need to sum over all integers. Since your random variable is only defined for positive integers $1,2,3,4,...$ your expected value is a series starting from $1$. Hence you have a series of the form $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} p^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p^k - 1$.

Comment: To be accurate you need to sum over all non-negative integers

Answer (score 1):

Note that, by  definition $$\boxed{\mathbb{E}[Y]=\sum_{y \in S_{Y}}yp(y)}$$
where $\boxed{S_{Y}=\{1,2,...,\}}$.
So, $$\mathbb{E}[Y]=\sum_{k\geq 1}\left( \frac{1}{2^{k}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2^{k}}\right)=-1+\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^{2}}}=\boxed{\frac{1}{3}}.$$